# Socket.io will not work unless being run locally

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, socket.io

I have a game made with React & Node, where it uses almost exclusively sockets to handle the events. Now, everything works exactly as I need it to when I run it locally, but as soon as I host it, I get all sorts of nothing happening, and I could really use a hand. I searched far and wide for an answer with no luck. I think I may know where the problem is, just not how to fix it.

SERVER

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const server = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(server);
const path = require("path");
const sockets = require("./sockets_controller");

app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/../build`));

io.of("/create").on("connection", socket => {

  socket.on("create game", user => sockets.createGame(user, socket));

});

...More namepaces and event listeners...


server.listen(4001, () => console.log(`server running on port 4001`));

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../build/index.html"));
});
```

Again, works perfect on localhost: but heres how I connect on the front end

Each of my components have a namespace associated with them, so in each component that uses sockets I have

```
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";
const socket = socketIOClient("http://localhost:4001/NAMEPSACE");
```

I saw on here that I should try to just use socketIOClient(), which SORTA works, but I lose my namespace and whatever I emit goes unheard by the sockets listening on the server.

I get the following error when I load the hosted version

```
The origin 'http://www.mywebsite.com' did not find 'http://www.mywebsite.com' in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header for cross-origin  resource at MY_IP
```

I have to imagine that I have to change localhost to something, but I just cant be sure.

EDIT: I have also tried socketIOClient("http://IP:4001/NAMEPSACE") and just socketIOClient("http://IP/NAMEPSACE") and still nothing is working

Comment: your client side code cannot be referencing `http://localhost:4001/NAMESPACE`, because that tells your browser to look at your own computer, not the server in which the backend code is hosted. You need to find out what the IP Address is of the remote host, and then make sure your front-end components are using that IP address when attempting to connect.

Comment: I have done this, same error
EDIT: When I changed it to the IP, I didn't specify the port. I guess ill try 'http://ip:4001/namespace'

Comment: Okay, I got it. I was able to get it working by doing socketIOClient = ('/namepace), works like a charm now

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I got it to work by changing 
`const socket = socketIOClient("http://localhost:4001/NAMEPSACE")`

to

`const socket = socketIOClient('/NAMESPACE)`